# asp.net razor and jQuery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, autocomplete

Hey i want to autocomplete this html text input:

```
$("#Supplier").autocomplete({

                source: availableTags
            });
```

and i have array of strings came from the controller to the view:

```
@ViewBag.VendorsArray
```

I can use it like this:

```
var availableTags = @ViewBag.VendorsArray;
```

and than use is in the "source" option of the autocomplete plugin?
Its didnt work for me.
Just if i make manually arrray like this:

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC"
                  ];
```

Than, its work.

Answer (score 0):

At first pass a coma separated string your ViewBag object then set to a javascript variable then convert the variable to javascript array.

**Please flow the example:**

@{ViewBag.VendorsArray =  "ActionScript,AppleScript,Asp,BASIC";}

```
<script>
     var list = "@ViewBag.VendorsArray";
      var availableTags = list.split(',');
        $("#Supplier").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I dont need comma seperated string to pass the autocomplete plugin, i need array of strings.

Comment: if you are unable to convert your string array to c# string then you can't send it to savascript. I use this appose over two years.

Comment: basically you can't send C# object to javascript. But in .cshtml when the the page is render then it white to HTTP response stream as a string. so javascript array like a coma separated string without bracket, for this reason this technique is work.